# checking whether values in list are equal is returning wrong result

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program in which I can input a list and if all the values in the list are equal, it returns the boolean Yahtzee as True.  When I run it, it works 99% of the time. However, index 3 can be different than the other values in the list and `isYahtzee()` will still return Yahtzee as True.  Can someone help me debug this?

```
#Determine whether all of them are the same and returns a Boolean.
def isYahtzee(aList):
    #This tells the program to look down the entire length of the list        
    for i in range (0,len(aList)):
    #Since I will be working with a list with no more than 5 numbers, I se
        #This equal to 5 indexs (0-4)
        if aList[0] == aList[1] and aList[1] and aList[2] and aList[3] and aList[4]:
            #If all of them are equal, the boolean Yahtzee = True
            Yahtzee = True

        #If they are not all equal to eachother    
        if aList[0] != aList[i]:
            #The Boolean Yahtzee = False
            Yahtzee = False

    #Return the value of the Boolean        
    return Yahtzee
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check to see if the list is length 5 and if the [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) of the list is length 1.

```
#Determine whether all of them are the same and returns a Boolean.
def isYahtzee(aList):
    return (len(aList) == 5 and len(set(aList)) == 1)
```

That being said, your problem is that you're only testing for equality of `aList[0] == aList[1]` -- the `and aList[1] and aList[2] and aList[3] and aList[4]` segment only checks to make sure that the other values exist, not that they are equal to `aList[0]`.

If you wanted to make it more strict, you could also add `and all(isinstance(item, int) for item in aList)` in order to check that all values are integers, and `and max(aList) <= 6 and min(aList) >= 1` in order to check if all the values are valid (standard) die values.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach, to avoid an expensive `set` build when you don't need one.

```
def isYahtzee(aList):
    return all(item==aList[0] for item in aList)
```

This will require that two items don't test `True` for equivalency when they're not actually the same, but unless you're building custom classes for dice and including those (rather than the die rolls they produce) in your `list`, it shouldn't be an issue in this implementation.